# new_to_publish fires multiple times

Tags: hooks, publish

i have been trying to use draft_to_publish & new_to_publish
to create an update when ever a post of a specific type (cpt) is published...

it works but published 600+ times instead of one time!

**So... my question is**

1. why does this happen & how to verify it only posts once
   (took me 10 minutes to delete)

**here is code i currently have:**

```
add_action('new_to_publish', 'new_webnews_published');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'new_webnews_published');
function new_webnews_published($post_id){

    $postData       =   get_post($post_id);
    $post_id        =   $post_id;
    $postData       =   get_post($post_id);
    $postType       =   get_post_type($post_id);
    $postTitle      =   $postData->post_title;


    if($postType == 'webnews') {

        // LINK TO WEBNEWS PAGE
        $webnewsPage    =   of_get_option(THEME_NAME.'_webnews_select_page');   

        // PREPARE UPDATE DATA
        $update_title   =   __('News',THEME_NAME);
        $update_content =   $postTitle;
        $update_url     =   'index.php?p='.$webnewsPage;


        $post = array(
            'post_title'    => $update_title, 
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'miniupdate'
        );

        $updatedid  = wp_insert_post($post, 10, 1);

        // Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
        do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post', 10, 1); 
        update_post_meta($updatedid, THEME_PREF.'miniupdates_content', $update_content);
        update_post_meta($updatedid, THEME_PREF.'miniupdates_link', $update_url);

    }
}
```

.
**Last Thing:**
i would like to test variables
example: "echo 'something';

i guess i need to create a second function and attach to admin_init?
But what are the timing restriction here?  should i add something to the
initial draft_to_publish hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OK! found how to** - there is 2 little information about
how to attach a function to a status change but this hook
does the job and does it well.

```
function miniupdate_webnews( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $old_status == 'draft' && $new_status == 'publish' ) {

         // YOUR FUNCTION HERE...

    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'miniupdate_webnews', 10, 3 );
```